# Pandas sumproduct

Tags: python, pandas, sum, product

I have a df:

```
Value1  Value2  1   2   3
  1       A     0   1   2
  2       B     3   4   5
  3       C     2   2   2
```

I want to perform sumproduct between the rows and the columns 1 2 3:

```
Value1  Value2  1   2   3   sumproduct
  1       A     0   1   2   8    = 0*1 + 1*2 + 2*3
  2       B     3   4   5   26   = 3*1 + 4*2 + 5*3
  3       C     2   2   2   12   = 2*1 + 2*2 + 2*3
```

I've tried `(df.values*df.columns.values).sum(1)` but then I need to drop `Value1` and `Value2` columns first.  Is there a better approach?

Many thanks!

Comment: I would like to do it without actually writing out df[1] df[2] df[3] ect... since there might be many more columns.

Comment: Take a look on "universal" version :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [0, 3, 2], '2': [1, 4, 2], '3': [2, 5, 2]})    
df['sumproduct'] = df[1] * 1 + df[2] * 2 + df[3] * 3
```

**UPDATE for generic case**

```
valid_columns = [col for col in df.columns if col.isdigit()]
df['sumproduct'] = (df[valid_columns] * [int(x) for x in valid_columns]).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you :) however, i would like to do it without actually writing out df[1] df[2] ect... since there might be many more columns

Comment: iterate over columns, select only able to convert to int, apply on df

Comment: I think my main problem is that the columns 1,2,3 are not in.  I tried to convert them into int with df.colums = df.columns.astype(int), but I would get an error with other string columns

Comment: instead of type(col) == int use col.isdigit() and convert while calculating. @TylerNG I have made update

Answer (score 9):

What I will do

```
df.iloc[:,2:].dot([1,2,3])
Out[239]: 
0     8
1    26
2    12
dtype: int64
```

To make it automatic

```
s=df.iloc[:,2:]

s.dot(s.columns.astype(int))
Out[242]: 
0     8
1    26
2    12
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [0]*len(df)
for i, v in enumerate([c for c in df.columns if not isinstance(c,str)]):
    arr = arr + df[v]*v

df['sumproduct'] = arr
```

or even:

```
cols = [c for c in df.columns if not isinstance(c, str)]
# or as @ilia
cols = pd.to_numeric(df.columns,errors='coerce').dropna()

df[cols].apply(lambda x: x*x.name).sum(axis='columns')
```

Comment: for some reason, the result is off.  [5,14,6]

Comment: This solution doesn't work in case there are other columns names not containing 'Value'. Consider this example df = pd.DataFrame({'hi' : [2, 5, 2], 1: [0, 3, 2], 2: [1, 4, 2], })

Comment: @DavidLeon How would this change if there are different column names?

Comment: Furthermore if there columns names will be not increased by 1 and in valid order, there also will be a problem. Check this case: df = pd.DataFrame({10: [2, 5, 2], 2: [0, 3, 2], 4: [1, 4, 2], }). Valid solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957782/3601806

Comment: @TylerNG, @biniow this answer is not generic indeed but fits the question as given. If columns are not the same please give me a naming structure to respect.
@TylerNG if not increase by 1, cast `float(v)` instead of i+1.

Comment: I would have like: Name1 ID Value2 1 2 3 4 5...  My apology for not being clear enough

Comment: updated, to get only not string type columns and using `v` instead of `i+1`

Answer (score 1):

```py
(df[['1','2','3']]*[1,2,3]).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```py
0   8
1   26
2   12
```

**Update:**
Universal approach

```py
col = pd.to_numeric(df.columns,errors='coer')
(df[df.columns[~pd.isnull(col)]]*col.dropna()).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: I got ValueError: Invalid broadcasting comparison [Float64Index([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype='float64')] with block values

Comment: what is you `pandas.__version__`?

Comment: What  df.info() prints?

Comment: I got this: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Value1        3 non-null int64
Value2        3 non-null object
1             3 non-null int64
2             3 non-null int64
3             3 non-null int64
sumproduct    3 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(4), object(1)
memory usage: 224.0+ bytes

Comment: It works in my environment :(
`pandas 0.21.0`, `python 3.6`
but perhaps problem is in `dtype` of your DataFrame.
Try `(df[df.columns[~pd.isnull(col)]].apply(pd.to_numeric)*col.dropna()).sum(axis=1)  `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165743/discussion-between-ilia-timofeev-and-tylerng).